# Web Api POST Request: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have my Web Api application distributed on more servers.

My situation is this:

```
                                     ---------------------
                                     -   LOAD BALANCER   -
                                     ---------------------


        -----------             -------------        -------------        --------------
          SERVER 1                 SERVER 2             SERVER 3             SERVER 4
        -----------             -------------        -------------        --------------
```

I have the list of servers ip.
The main call performed is:

```
http://webapidefault/mywebapi/v01/method
```

This url make the load balancer choose a server on witch the request have to be executed.
I'd like to perform this operation on all the servers.

I've think to use the ip addresses of the servers to compose a POST request and when the main call is received by one of the server, the server itself calls the others as:

```
http://serverIP/mywebapi/v01/method
```

When i launch the request it returns the 401 unauthorize error.

How can i solve the situation?

The code I run is the following:

```
[Route("methodtoperformonallservers")]
[HttpPost]
public ResponseMessageResult PerformAllServers()
{
  var result = MyHelper.PerformAll();

  if(result != -1)
  {
      return WebHelper.CreateResponseMessageResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
  }
  else
  {
      return WebHelper.CreateResponseMessageResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, result);
  } 
}
```

My helper will execute:

```
public static int PerformAll()
{
   foreach( var serverIP in serverList)
   {
      var reqStr = http://serverIP/mywebapi/v01/methodtoperformonspecificserver;
      var reqUri = new Uri(reqStr);
      var myrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(reqUri);
      myrequest.Method = "POST";
      myrequest.ContentLenght = 0;

      var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
      .
      .
      .
      .
   }
}
```

When the GetResponse is called it throws the 401 exception.

How can i solve my situation? Thank you in advance.

Best regards

Comment: What was the issue and how did you get around it?

Answer (score 0):

With the Firefox add-on `Headertool` you can add an `Authorize` line in the HTTP headers to fix the unauthorize error.

With [Fiddler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiddler_%28software%29) you can trace and debug the HTTP messages.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me why you want/need to execute the method on all 4 servers. A load-balancer is usually useful when you want to spread the load over several servers and not to execute a process on all servers.

If this is for some kind of maintenance jobs, I would suggest to implement the logic in a client rather than within your API.

Anyway, I don't think that the error you are getting (http error 401) has nothing to do with your method execution. This is because your request is not authenticated and the API expects some credentials.

How is your API secure? Has it ever been working on one of those 4 servers?